# How to display text if the field is empty?

Tags: templates, drupal, twig, drupal-8

How to display a text if the field is empty ?

I tried the following code but it does not work :

```
    {% if content.field_description is not empty %}
      {{ content.field_description }}
    {% else %}
      test
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: Whats not working? Should work as is, see [here](https://twigfiddle.com/jemo6a)

Answer (score 1):

If you have Twig Tweak installed, you can do the following:

```
{% if content['field_description'] | field_value != '' %}
  {{ content['field_description'].value | striptags }}
{% else %}
  <p class="des-empty">test</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

When field is empty it is not coming with content variable
so you can simply check by `isset`

```
{% if content.field_description %}
  {{ content.field_description }}
{% else %}
  <p class="des-empty">test</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you I just tested but it does not work. If the field is empty, it does not display the replacement text `{% if content.field_description %}
          {{ content.field_description }}
        {% else %}
          <p>Quel dommage, ce membre n'a malheureusement pas encore complété sa présentation. Si vous souhaitez en savoir plus sur lui, vous pouvez le contacter par le biais de sa messagerie privée.</p>
        {% endif %}`

Comment: this is the main issue for same problem many solutions are at same page i hope you will find yours https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2547559

Answer (score 0):

The below worked for me:

```
{% if content['field_description'] IS NOT EMPTY %}
  {{ content['field_description'].value | striptags }}
{% else %}
  <p class="des-empty">test</p>
{% endif %}
```

Please note that it may vary based on the content type and fields you are dealing with.